# In Unity trying to convert a Base64String to a png

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, png

I'm getting a Base64String from an API (Stable Horde)
I tried using

```
filePath = some path + image.png
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(myImageData.generations[0].img));
```

This does create an image on the hard drive but its not really a png image so when I try to read all bytes
back into an image in the scene there is a problem. Doesn't work. I figured out that this is because it was not encoded correctly into a real png in the first place.

I'm trying to translate this python code (into Unity C#) that does create an actual png:

```
 
  b64img = results[iter]["img"]
            base64_bytes = b64img.encode('utf-8')
            img_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_bytes)
            img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_bytes))
            if len(results) > 1:
                final_filename = f"{iter}_{filename}"
            img.save(final_filename)
```

I've been trying solutions searching online for about 16 hours with no luck. Can't believe how poorly documented and hard to do this is?

Can anyone help? What's the correct way to take a Base64String and convert it to a png in Unity C#.
Thanks!

Comment: The code is identical to what was suggested below. The error thrown is: 
 ArgumentException: Could not create sprite (0, 0, 512, 512) from a 8x8 texture. And the texture shows as a red question mark.

Comment: I'm getting a Base64String from an API (Stable Horde)

Comment: Here is an example of the api string returned to unity: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tonKm7dXBtzoDYfXhdXRlew-XRrotSf3/view                                                                        I removed the beginning                                                                                               {"generations": [ {"img": "                                                                                                                     and the everything after the ==

Comment: Never use encoding with binary data.  UTF-8 will change some bytes like 0x80.

Comment: >Never use encoding with binary data. UTF-8 will change some bytes like 0x80.  Ok, do you have any suggestions as to how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Find out was was really used to create the Base64 string.  I doubt the people who sent you the file corrupted the file using encoding.  An image has an ascii header followed by image bytes.  You can modify the ascii header, but the image bytes cannot be modified.  Open the image with notepad or any text header and look at the ascii header.

Comment: here is the base64string:     https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tonKm7dXBtzoDYfXhdXRlew-XRrotSf3/view      I am able to convert it to show an image on the hard drive but its not a real PNG. Photoshop confirms this.

Comment: File is a RIFF(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format).  Looks like the Base64 string is in a json transmission. I extract the data between the double quotes and then ran FromBase64 string to byte and saved in file..  Then opened file with notepad.  The first four characters are the type RIFF which is the ASCII Header. WebP (An image format developed by Google)

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for letting me know. So when I convert this that Base64 string in Python (just as a sanity check), my python code creates a PNG, not a WebP image. This leads me to believe that the C#  method WriteAllBytes is converting/saving the Base64 string as a Webp file to disk. Strange that this is the default. Such an unwieldy image type for Unity

Comment: "File.WriteAllBytes" is image-agnostic, it only writes whatever the bytes are. If you look at the [StableHorde API docs](https://stablehorde.net/api/), it says for GenerationStable "The generated image as a Base64-encoded **.webp** file". If you google [unity convert webp to png] you get some pointers, though you may also request from the Stable Horde team to offer a PNG delivery option in the API.

Comment: Yeah seems like it makes more sense to request a PNG delivery. The options for Unity conversion from WebP to PNG don't look promising. Thanks!

Comment: I guess there is no option built into C# for Unity (some other method) that allows the data that is written by File.WriteAllBytes method to be saved as PNG. This looks like something that python is able to do natively since when I run the same Base64 string through my python code is does create an actual PNG image file on disk (I opened the image file in note pad to verify)

Comment: Any image processing tool should check ascii header for type of file.  What library is being use to convert bytes to image?

Comment: Do web search for "msdn c# image riff webp"  Also see : https://programmingcsharp.com/webp-images-asp-net/

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the link to the Webp library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string base64String = "(your base64 string)";
byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(0, 0);
ImageConversion.LoadImage(texture, data);
```

Comment: you can use `texture.LoadImage(data);` .. it is an extension method ;)

Comment: Also not sure tbh if OP actually wants this to be loaded to a texture necessarily ... OP is trying to directly write it to a file

Comment: Ok sure, let's see. OP says "when I try to read all bytes back into an image in the scene there is a problem" so I figure there's a chance they might want to display it on some quad or cube or such. If not, we can amend.

Comment: of course good catch .. we will wait until OP shows us also the way how they tried to load the data ^^ Though after saving it as an actual png file I would rather use a `UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture` or loading

Comment: Edited to add file saving example as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried all these methods and they result in the scene image showing a red question mark.  here is the error thrown:                                            ArgumentException: Could not create sprite (0, 0, 512, 512) from a 8x8 texture.

Comment: As I mentioned in the body of the post I am also using File.WriteAllBytes("my file path", data); This DOES create a file that appears to be an image in Windows explorer but when you try to open it in Phototshop is says not a PNG. Interestingly, if you use Resources.Load and load this image file (that shows as not a PNG) from the resource folder, it will display in the scene properly showing the image on a texture in the unity scene, i.e. the same image that can be seen in windows explorer.

Comment: I would just use the Resources.load solution but this app will be deployed in a meta quest (apk - android build) and you can not save and load images that are created on-the-fly into the the resources folder. apparently this is baked in when the app is build and there is not access to it during runtime.

Comment: It might be a JPG then -- what happens if you open the image file on your disk with a text editor, does the start say something more like "PNG" or "JFIF"?

Comment: @derHugo - I just realized why I had used ImageConversion.LoadImage() instead of texture.LoadImage() -- it's because the latter showed [only in the legacy documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html) in the Unity docs when googling it and the former shows [in the recent one](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html). Not sure if Google just missed the reference, though (and both work).

Comment: I opened with a text editor and here are some of the characters: "RIFFNÞ  WEBPVP8" on the first line

Comment: @mgh : File is RIFF which is the ASCII header.  See my comments above.  WebP (An image format developed by Google)

Comment: "File.WriteAllBytes" is image-agnostic, it only writes whatever the bytes are. If you look at the [StableHorde API docs](https://stablehorde.net/api/), it says for GenerationStable "The generated image as a Base64-encoded **.webp** file". If you google [unity convert webp to png] you get some pointers, though you may also request from the Stable Horde team to offer a PNG delivery option in the API.